# Internal microphone does not work on internet browser

Tags: sound, microphone

I am studying on [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) and I have to use microphone for some speaking exercises. However, it seems that my internal microphone does not work!

I tested in `gstreamer-properties`
and it worked okay. I can hear my voice also. But it does not work on the site. I have no idea what went wrong.